# Firebase Crashlytics: Combine/Merge Similar Issues?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I had Firebase Crashlytics installed in my Android app, and the reporting is operational.

However, I found that some issues are very similar:

[image: Firebase Crashlytics with similar issues]

And it'd be helpful if I could treat them as the same issue when debugging or closing.

Is there any chances I can merge them into one?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to merge these crashes. Crashlytics will group the issues based on the frame being blamed. In this case, even though they look similar, the frame is under a different line number.

You could file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) for this behavior.